# Intermittently cannot push/pull from GitHub. Getting SSL errors

Tags: git, ssl

I'm having trouble pushing and pulling from GitHub. I checked [status.github.com](https://status.github.com/messages) and they are not having problems.

Occasionally I get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/x/x.git/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

So to push to my repository, I keep doing a `git push` until it works.

When I go to `github.com` via HTTPS on my web browser, the site sometimes hangs at "establishing secure connection" and lags.

This happened suddenly, and I have not changed any settings on my computer, so what is going on?

FWIW:

- I restarted my computer.
- This is my home network connection. Not connected to a VPN.
- My Git client is updated.

Comment: Do you have packet loss on your internet connection?

Comment: This meant that the Let's Encrypt servers took too long to respond. Just try again after some time.